# In R, how can I convert SpatialPolygons* to map objects

Tags: r, ggplot2, gis, geospatial, spatial

I'm trying to make use of `ProportionalSymbolMap` map as defined in this [JSS paper](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v15/i05).

In order to plot proportional symbols I first need an object of map class.

The [methods](http://www.nceas.ucsb.edu/scicomp/usecases/ReadWriteESRIShapeFiles) I normally use however return SpatialPolygonDataFrame. Is there any package or method that could be of help here?

Comment: What packages are you using?

Comment: @SimonO101 I was hoping for hacking my way towards proportional symbol map in ggplot but am open to any solutions.

Answer (score 4):

*Hack* is the way to go about it. I just used this set of commands to take apart a SpatialPolygons* object and put it back together again as an object of class `map`. I hope you like it:

```
# read in shapefile as normal SpatialPolygons
xx <- readShapePoly(system.file("shapes/sids.shp", package="maptools")[1], IDvar="FIPSNO", proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=clrk66"))

# Formatting the data
require(reshape)
# Identifier column to split data on
xx@data$id <- rownames(xx@data)

# Convert to dataframe
xx.df <- as.data.frame(xx)

#Fortfy automagic
xx.fort <- fortify(xx, region="id")

# Join operation - one row per coordinate vector
xx <- join(xx.fort, xx.df,by="id")

# Split by ID because we need to add NA at end of each set of polygon coordinates to 'break' the line
xxSp <- split(xx, xx$id)

# Need to insert NA at end of each polygon shape to cut off that shape
xxL <- do.call( rbind , (lapply( xxSp , function(x) { j <- x[ nrow(x) , ] ; j[1:2] <- c(NA,NA); rbind( x , j ) })) )


# Create list object with same structure as map object
xxMap <- list( x = xxL$long , y = xxL$lat , range = c( range(xxL$long) , range(xxL$lat) ) , names = as.character(unique( xxL$NAME ) ) )

# Define as a map class object
attr(xxMap , "class") <- "map"

# Plot!!
map( xxMap )
```

[image]

Comment: @radek is there something more you need for this solution to be useful for you? Cheers.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Thanks a lot for that. It does seem to work, however there are some strange artifacts on the converted map. If you compare it to original file - there are some strange connections between polygons on the left edge of the map. What might be causing those?

Comment: @radek I didn't notice those - possibly holes in polygons, but almost certainly to do with the arrangement of the x/y coordinates. If I get some time I will look into it further. For you shapefiles does it work ok? Or do you have the same problem?

Comment: Only tested it with your example so far. I suspect it might cause problems with my data as well since I work with quite complex administrative boundaries (holes, islands, multipart features, etc.). Will give it a shot tho asap!

Comment: @radek I forgot to ask - how did you get on with this method? I should like to have another crack if you experienced the same problems like I did above.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I got the same problems with polygons using my data. So for the moment I abandoned idea and trying to hack my way to make proportional symbols using base plot.

Comment: @radek I'll have another look at it this evening if I get anytime. Cheers!